# Path tracing shadows with Three.js

Tags: javascript, path, three.js, webgl, light

I'm trying to experiment with ways to create a more realistic look in webGL and stumbled on this demo http://madebyevan.com/webgl-path-tracing/.

I'm fairly new to javascript and have been using THREE.JS to learn webGL.  I noticed in the demo they use a sylvester.src.js which I assume is calculating the path tracing for the lights/shadows.  Can path traced lighting be used with threejs? If so how?

Sorry to be so vague on this one.  I haven't found much info to go off of in this matter.

Comment: searching google for "three.js raytracer" yields many results. even a [demo](http://threejs.org/examples/raytracing_sandbox.html)

Comment: thank you for responding. I've searched for both "three.js raytracer" and "three.js path tracing" and have been unable to find the relevant information.  I'm hoping to achieve path tracing like the example in the link in the post within the realm of the three.js source.